# What documents are required to apply for a B1/B2 visa?

Tags: visas, usa, paperwork, b1-b2-visas

Do i need any invitation letter from my visitor if I am traveling to USA as a tourist? Also, this visa was issued to me by my company, can I use the same visa to travel again to USA for tourism purposes? If yes, what additional documents are required from my end?

Comment: I doubt your company _issued_ the visa -- if it did so, it is fake. Visas are _issued_ by consular representations of the host country. Your company may have handled the paperwork involved in _applying_ for the visa, but the _issuer_ is still the U.S. government.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your visa actually says "B1/B2" under "visa type/class", then it's a combined business and tourist visa, which is valid for either purpose. It can be used again if it is still valid and was issued for multiple entries.

If it says only "B1" (which appears to be rare but possible), then it's a pure business visa and not valid for tourism.

You don't need an invitation letter for ordinary tourism (after the visa has been issued), but you need to be able to answer questions about your plans and itinerary convincingly at the border. Having tickets and hotel reservations ready to show is strongly recommended. If you're staying privately, have full contact details for your hosts with you. (Having a letter from your host could be helpful if you're depending on them for financial support during your visit and can't show sufficient funds of your own at the border).

Comment: Thanks much! I do have my tickets with me but I am planning to stay with my spouse who is traveling for business purpose during same time. Hence all hotel bookings are under his name. Will that be an issue ?

Comment: Also I am reading conflicting posts which say that if B1/B2 was issued by company , i can't use it for my personal travel for tourism if company name is stamped on the visa page. I don't see my company name stamped on my visa page anywhere , are there any other encoding/attributes which I should be verifying ?

Comment: @TopCoder: If you're entering together, then it shouldn't be a problem that the hotel reservations is in the name of one of you. If you're entering alone to join your husband who is already traveling, it might raise some eyebrows, and you should think in advance about what you can do to document the facts. Again, there are no _formal_ requirements for presenting such-and-such documents, only "whatever happens to convince the border guard that you're legit".

Comment: There is no such thing as _"B1/B2 issued by company"_